# Having a problem with my mergeSort implementation

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm getting an out of bounds error for my implementation of `mergeSort`, and I can't figure out why. This is the exact error message: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1"`

Here's my implementation of `mergeSort`:

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] arr, int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return;
    }
    
    int mid_index = n / 2; 
    int[] left = new int[mid_index];
    int[] right = new int[n - mid_index];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < mid_index; i++) {
        left[i] = arr[i];
    }
    
    for (int i = mid_index; i < n; i++) {
        right[i - mid_index] = arr[i];
    }
    
    mergeSort(left, mid_index);
    mergeSort(right, n - mid_index);
    merge(arr, left, right, mid_index, n - mid_index);
}
    
public static void merge(int[] arr, int[] left, int[] right, int left_length, int right_length) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0; 
    int k = 0; 
    
    while (j < left_length && k < right_length) {
        if (left[i] < right[j]) {
            arr[k] = left[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = right[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    
    while (j < left_length) {
        arr[k] = left[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    
    while (i < right_length) {
        arr[k] = right[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: In which line you have ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in `merge` method. You make some mistakes with indexes. I corrected them in code below

```
public static void merge(int[] arr, int[] left, int[] right, int left_length, int right_length){
    int i = 0;//left
    int j = 0; //right
    int k = 0; 
    
    while(i<left_length && j < right_length){
        if(left[i] < right[j]){
            arr[k] = left[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else{
            arr[k] = right[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    
    while(i<left_length){
        arr[k] = left[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    
    while(j<right_length){
        arr[k] = right[j];
        k++;
        j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Nosrep What is OP?

Comment: The person who asked the question

Comment: I see that I accidentally switched i and j in the last 2 while loops, but I'm still getting the same error when I run it "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1"

Comment: Also change in `while(i<left_length && j < right_length){`

Answer (score 1):

All 3 `while` loop in the `merge` method use the wrong index variables. The first loop `while (j < left_length && k < right_length) {` should be

```
    while (i < left_length && j < right_length) {
```

The second loop `while (j < left_length) {` should be

```
    while (i < left_length) {
```

Finally, the last loop `while (i < right_length) {` should be

```
    while (j < right_length) {
```